# Python Sqlalchemy: Filter by datediff of months

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to translate the following to sqlalchemy:

```
SELECT COUNT(TableA.id) AS 'number_of_staff' 
FROM   TableA 
WHERE  datediff(month, TableA.Date, getDate()) >= 0
       AND lookup_TableB = '4'
       AND (TableA.End_Date IS NULL OR TableA.End_Date = '')
```

So far I have:

```
get_tablea_number = self.db_session.query(func.count(TableA.id)).\
        filter(TableA.lookup_TableB == property_id, 
               todays_date.month - extract('month',  TableA.date) >= 0,
               or_(TableA.end_date == None,
                   TableA.end_date == '')).scalar()
```

However it outputs different values to the above sql query, which I'm assuming is down to `todays_date.month - extract('month',  TableA.date) >= 0` (where `todays_date.month` is just a datetime object)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`todays_date.month - extract('month',  TableA.date) >= 0` will probably not do what you want if the difference between "today" and `TableA.date` is over a year, e.g. 2016-04 and 2015-10 results in (analogous python here):

```
In [8]: today = date.today()  # datetime.date(2016, 4, 12)

In [9]: a_date = date(2015,10,10)

In [10]: today.month - a_date.month
Out[10]: -6
```

On the other hand what the [`datediff` function of SQL server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) does is:

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.

There are 6 months in between 2016-04 and 2015-10, so that would be the correct result for:

```
datediff(month, '2015-10-10', '2016-04-12')
```

So what you have to do is use the correct function in python with sqlalchemy as well:

```
from sqlalchemy import func, text

func.datediff(text('month'), TableA.date, todays_date) >= 0
```

The [`text('month')`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) is a way to pass the literal SQL `month` to SQL server:

```
In [16]: print(func.datediff(text('month'), datetime.now(), datetime.now()))
datediff(month, :datediff_1, :datediff_2)
```

[`literal_column`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column) might work as well.

If you want a closer translation, replace `todays_date` in python with the SQL function you used in the original:

```
func.datediff(text('month'), TableA.date, func.getDate()) >= 0
```

Comment: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'

Comment: @tarun Wrong database. This is for Microsoft SQL Server, you're using MariaDB/MySQL.

Comment: For MySQL/MariaDB remove the 1st parameter `text('month')`. The MariaDB Version of `datediff` works with days by default.