# sqlalchemy generic datetime arithmetic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I'am trying to query an date intervall.
i tried this one:

```
session.query(Entity).filter(Entity.EntityDate < Entity.EntityDate2 - datetime.timedelta(days=-31).all()
```

But with Azure SQL Server, i get the following Error

> The data types datetime and datetime2 are incompatible in the add operator

I tried several thing i found here or on google (e.g. func.dateadd...), but all those solutions doesn't look generic for all Databases.

Is there a generic sqlalchemy solution for such a column based date arithmetic operation ?

Comment: `func.dateadd` and `func.datediff `are part of sqlalchemy. That being said they should be generic and can be used in the same manner for different dbs. Give it a go :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571706/python-sqlalchemy-filter-by-datediff-of-months Will be a good example to get you started

Comment: As far as i understand the link, dateadd and datediff are sql server specific.
That'sy why the sqlalchemy docs dont't find "datediff" oder "dateadd" either :-(